# Webdriverio iOS restart app with processArguments

Tags: javascript, ios, webdriver, appium, webdriver-io

I have iOS app which implemented UI testing with Appium.
And when I want to restart app with this code, processArguments are lost.
Could anyone tell me how to restart app without losing processArguments or pass processArguments when restart app?

```
await driver.terminateApp(bundleId);
await driver.activateApp(bundleId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to pass arguments in drvier.execute function.
Here's the solution.

```
const restartApp = async () => {
  await driver.terminateApp(bundleId);
  const processArgs = ['--mock-fes-api', '--mock-attester-api']; // your process arguments
  const args = {
    bundleId, // your bundle id
    arguments: processArgs
  }
  await driver.execute('mobile: launchApp', args);
}
```